# A case of induction! $ n^3 − n^2 + 1 $ is an odd number for all n ∈ N.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, natural-numbers

So I am learning about induction and I am trying to prove that

**$(n^3 - n^2 + 1)$ is an odd number for all n ∈ N (natural number)**

**I want to see if I am on the right track to understanding this and if my reasoning makes sense :)**

**STEP 1: Base Case**

So we first need to solve for the base case which we can say is n = 1.

$(1^3 - 1^2 + 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 = 1)$

Since 1 is odd, the base case holds! Onward to induction step.

**STEP 2: Inductive Step:**

We have some arbitrary positive integer k.

We can assume $ (k^3 - k^2 + 1) $ is odd. Using the natural number of $ k+1$ we can write

$(k+1)^3 - (k+1)^2 + 1 $

Expanding it out.....

$(k+1)^3 - (k+1)^2 + 1$

= $k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 - (k^2 + 2k + 1) + 1$

= $(k^3 - k^2 + 1) + 3k^2 + 3k$

Now, we know that $k^3 - k^2 + 1$ is odd and $3k^2 + 3k$ is always even (since it's divisible by 3).

Given that we assume $(k^3 - k^2 + 1)$ is odd

...and the sum of an odd number and an even number is always odd

...$ (k+1)^3 - (k+1)^2 + 1)$ is also odd

We proved the induction!

Comment: I'm happy that you understand induction. But what exactly is your question?

Comment: It's not obvious to me how you conclude.  Letting $s_k=k^3-k^2+1$, you appear to have proven that $s_{k+1} =k^3+2k^2+k+1$...but how is that enough?

Comment: Worth noting:  it's *much* easier to prove this directly, without induction.  Just remark that $n^3-n^2=n\times n\times (n-1)$ and, as $n-1$ and $n$ have opposite parity, that expression is always even.

Comment: It works, but that statement is easier to prove without induction.

Comment: $3|21$ but $21$ is not even. Your argument ("since it's divisible by 3") does not hold.

Comment: In the last line you should have $$\cdots= (k^3-k^2+1)+k(3k+1)$$  The second addendum isalways even, not matter if $k$ is even or odd

Answer (score 1):

In line with @Marco,
it remains to be proven that $3k^2+k$ is even.

There are two cases:

> $k$ is even and then $k(3k+1)$ is even

> $k$ is odd and in this case, $3k$ is odd, $3k+1$ is even ; and finally $k(3k+1)$ is even.

In all cases, $3k^2+k$ is even

This type of reasoning is called *case-disjunction reasoning*.

---

On the other hand, it is desirable to conclude(**step 3**):

"We have proved by induction that : $$\forall n\in \mathbb N^*, n^3-n^2+1\text{ is odd.}"$$